# how to let js alert box pop up at the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

An alert box will pop up after I submit my registration form , but the alert box will always pop up in a blank page.

What can I do to let the alert box pop up at the same page of my registration form?

My alert box:

```
 if($query){
    echo  "<script>alert('Invoice sent succefully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href ='add-client.php'</script>";
    }}?>
```

[Blank page where alert box pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNFY6.png)

Comment: Can you try to make your question more clear?

Comment: I want the alert box pop up in the same page of my registration form instead of a blank page.

Comment: If you're using an HTML form and a`submit` button then the browser sends the data and loads a new page. If you want to send the data without a page load you'll need to use AJAX. There are many tutorials on the web that cover this.